# How do I write to specific cells in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

How do I write to specific cells in Excel?

This works for writing to cells that have the titles "id" and "name" in the first row.

```
string stSheetName = "Sheet1";
string sql = "Insert into [" + stSheetName + "$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This does not work:

```
string sql = "Insert into [" + stSheetName + "$A2:B2] SET A2 = '5', B2 = 'e'";
```

Comment: I answer how to write data to an Excel file on [my blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net).

Comment: I used [epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)  with success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The (OleDbConnection) HDR=YES must be HDR=NO.  The following does work.

```
string sql = "UPDATE [" + stSheetName + "$B2:B2] SET F1='e'";
```